# Method called twice out of order in Page_Load

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, page-lifecycle

I asked this over in the SharePoint Stack Exchange but figured it might not be a SharePoint-specific question and might have more to do with the .NET page lifecycle.  The original question can be found [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/210235/how-do-sessions-interact-with-each-other).

I am writing a web app for SharePoint 2013 and am running into some interesting behavior.  Basically, I am making a series of web requests, but first need to store those in a `Dictionary` for use later.  However, if I open 3 tabs while debugging and hit them at the same time, I see the `Dictionary` object is not emptied and causes an exception when it tries to add the same endpoint multiple times.  Here is the relevant code of the app:

```
public partial class TestControl : UserControl
{
    protected static Dictionary<string, string> _endpoints = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //clear the lists of endpoints each time the page is loaded
        _endpoints.Clear();
        ...
        MethodThatAddsToDictionary();
       ...
    }

    public static void MethodThatAddsToDictionary()
    {
        ...
        _endpoints.Add(response.First(), response.Last());
    }
}
```

Debugging, sometimes `MethodThatAddsToDictionary()` is called twice before the `_endpoints.Clear()` is run at the top under the `Page_Load` event and I'll get an `ArgumentException` saying:

> an item with the same key has already been added

I feel like I'm missing something basic about the lifecycle of the app but haven't found anything that works so far.  I could wrap the `.Add()` in a conditional to check for the key before I add it, but I feel like that is a bandaid.  What am I missing?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: why this ```protected static Dictionary<string, string> _endpoints``` is static?

Comment: The problem is that your pageload is handled by different threads and your dictionary is static. This means multiple pageloads can be executed at the same time. You can use a lock or reconsider the use of the static variable.

Comment: @tym32167 @Stefan I am using a static variable because the other methods in the application that use `_endpoints` are static.  I seem to recall trying to change that to not be `static` but it wouldn't let me use them like I wanted if I did that.

Comment: Even trying that now, I get an "object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property" error.

Comment: @awh112  can you call static methods and pass to them endpoints as parameter?

Comment: @tym32167 you mean just pass _endpoints where I need it from the `Page_Load` method?  I can try that, sure.

Comment: I mean like ```static void Foo(IDictionary<string, string> endpoints)``` => and you will able to call static method using non-static variable.

Comment: @tym32167 it looks like you were right, taking the `Dictionary` object and just passing it to the methods I needed rather than setting it as `static` resolved the issue.  If you want to write your comment as an answer I'll gladly accept it.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**ehhmm...**
*If you are not using the static dictionary as a sort of shared memory cache, you can drop all the static keywords your example code. In that case you also don't need to call the `Clear()` method.*

If you use your `static` dictionary as a sort of memory cache, which I wouldn't recommend, you might experience that multiple calls to your page will result in a race condition, since they might be handled by different threads. In order to fix this, you can, as a band-aid, use a lock statement to force thread synchronization on the non-thread-safe call to the dictionary like this:

```
public partial class TestControl : UserControl
{
    protected static Dictionary<string, string> _endpoints = 
                                      new Dictionary<string, string>();

    //lock object needs to be static in this case
    private static object _lockObject = new object();

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lock(_lockObject) //only one thread may pass at the same time,
                          //others will wait.
        {
            //clear the lists of endpoints each time the page is loaded
            _endpoints.Clear();
            ...
            MethodThatAddsToDictionary();

         }
     }

     public static void MethodThatAddsToDictionary()
     {
         ...
         _endpoints.Add(response.First(), response.Last());
     }
 }
```

Please note; this is a dirty fix and will effectively cancels all multithreading optimizations of the webs-server for this specific call (and thus causes a performance penalty).

Comment: Remoiving the `static` keyword is what I ended up doing, although I do wish there was a better way to set those "global" variables instead of using return values and setting them that way.  For now, though, it looks like I need to remove the `static` keywords to use it how I intended.

Comment: Hmmm.. I think there must be a better way indeed. Although it's not really clear to me what it is that you need. Maybe if you can explain a bit more we can help you to get on the right track. :-)

Comment: Thanks for your response!  I've created a separate question to track what I've done and what I'm running into now.  Take a look at it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42725790/setting-a-non-static-variable-in-separate-static-method.  Thanks for your help!