# Setting a non-static variable in separate static method

Tags: c#, asp.net

This question is an expansion of one I asked previously, linked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42719873/method-called-twice-out-of-order-in-page-load).

Since then, I have changed my application to not use `static` global variables for storing API endpoint information.  What I didn't mention was that I was also setting token variables aside from the `Dictionary`.  My code now looks something like this:

```
public partial class TestControl : UserControl
{
    private string _token = null;  //this used to be a static variable
    protected Dictionary<string, string> _endpoints = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //clear the lists of endpoints each time the page is loaded
        _endpoints.Clear();
        ...
        var sessionInfo = MethodThatAddsToDictionary(_endpoints, _token);
        //logic that sets the global tokens based on return values
        ...
    }

    public static Dictionary<string, string> MethodThatAddsToDictionary(Dictionary<string, string> endpoints, string token)
    {
        var returnedTokens = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        token = "returned_token";  //this doesn't set the global _token value
        ...
        endpoints.Add(response.First(), response.Last());
    }
}
```

In the `MethodThatAddsToDictionary()` I was setting the "global" variable `_token` straight from the method.  However, now that the variable is no longer static I can't do that.

I guess I have two fundamental questions with this setup:

1. Why does changing `endpoints` in `MethodThatAddsToDictionary()` change `_endpoints`?  I assume because it is a non-static variable.
2. Why doesn't this work the same for `_token`?

These questions seem like a nuance between passing-by-value and passing-by-reference but I'm not sure what I'm missing here.  For now I got away with just saving the token varaibles to a `Dictionary` that is returned and set the variables in `Page_Load` after the method call.

Thanks!

Comment: Hi, my question for you is; why do you need a global variable? Have you considered Session variables? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581.aspx? Or application variables: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/94xkskdf.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why does changing endpoints in `MethodThatAddsToDictionary()` change `_endpoints`?

Because you're passing `_endpoints` to the function, and `Dictionary` is a reference type, so `endpoints` is a reference to the same dictionary as `_endpoints`.

> Why doesn't this work the same for _token?

`string` is *also* a reference type, but you're not changing the value it's referring to, you're setting the reference to point to a *new* string value, which has no effect on the original value.

> These questions seem like a nuance between passing-by-value and passing-by-reference

Sort of.  *All* of the parameters are passed "by value", but for reference types (like `Dictionary`), the value *is* a reference to an object.  You *could* do something similar with `token` if you used the `ref` keyword before the parameter type, which *would* pass the string by reference.

Comment: Don't think `string` is a value type.. but it behaves like one (i did not downvote btw)

Comment: String is a reference type.  It behaves exactly like a reference type, not a value type.  Being a value type (for things that actually *are* value types) aren't necessarily immutable.  Both value types and reference types can be immutable; both reference types and value types can be mutable.

Comment: @BackDoorNoBaby I plead temporary insanity.  fixed.

Comment: Interesting - I figured it was something to do with the fact that I instantiated a `Dictionary` and didn't do the same for the `string` which made them fundamentally different.  This makes a lot of sense, thanks for the explanation!